# How to handle the result of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am starting the location services intent in order to get the location updates from the user:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent,100);
```

[image]

I then try to check the `resultCode` inside onActivityResult method(for now I'm simply toasting):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Result Code: " + resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I was expecting the `resultCode` to show a different result if the user toggles the location on or off. However I only get 0 as the result.

What criteria should I use to get whether or not the GPS was enabled?

Answer (score 2):

> I was expecting the resultCode to show a different result if the user toggles the location on or off.

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS) does not say that you get a result from that `Intent`.

> What criteria should I use to get whether or not the GPS was enabled?

Use [`LocationManager` and `isProviderEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#isProviderEnabled(java.lang.String)) to determine if your desired provider is enabled.